# How to Update Set using MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, set, sql-update

I have a simple, unsecured, local database that I'm learning with (yes still using MySQL for now) I can view my database rows in a table and click on an edit button which then displays the single record chosen with each column inside a text box to update and save.

This is part of my edit page which displays five text boxes that I'm attempting to update the db with

```
<?php
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
?>
<form action="updateinfo.php" method="post">
<tr>
  <td align="right">Partnumber:</td>
  <td align="left"><input type="text" name="partnumber" value="<?php echo $row['partnumber'];?>"/></td>
</tr>
```

Here is my updateinfo

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost","name","password") or die("Error: ".mysql_error()); 
mysql_select_db("toner");

$partnumber  = $_POST['partnumber'];
$description = $_POST['description'];
$vendor      = $_POST['vendor'];
$price       = $_POST['price'];
$quantity    = $_POST['quantity'];
$sql         = "UPDATE inventory SET partnumber ='".$partnumber."',description ='".$description."',vendor ='".$vendor."',price ='".$price."',quantity ='".$quantity."' WHERE partnumber = '".$partnumber ."'";

mysql_query($sql) or die ("Error: ".mysql_error());
echo "Database updated.";
header( "refresh:5;url =toner.php" );
?>
```

It displays Database updated but no changes are made, any assistance is appreciated, and yes I'm aware its vulnerable to injection and that I should be using PDO or MySQLi but I'm still a beginner and this is where I've chosen to start learning. Thank you.

Comment: if not a typo ..Close form tag <form action="updateinfo.php" method="post"

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Instead of this

```
<form action="updateinfo.php" method="post"

$sql = "UPDATE inventory SET partnumber ='".$partnumber."',description ='".$description."',vendor ='".$vendor."',price ='".$price."',quantity ='".$quantity."' WHERE partnumber = '".$partnumber ."'";
```

Use this :

```
<form action="updateinfo.php" method="post">

$sql = "UPDATE inventory SET partnumber ='".$partnumber."',description ='".$description."',vendor ='".$vendor."',price ='".$price."',quantity ='".$quantity."' WHERE partnumber = '".$partnumber."'";
```

Remove space from `'".$partnumber ."'`

Try now maybe it will help you.

Comment: I've replaced $sql = with your suggestion, does not seem to have any effect, thank you for your assistance however.

Comment: have you remove space from $partnumber ?

Comment: Or echo $partnumber and check it is display value or not ?

Comment: It does echo the new partnumber, its just not being entered into the db

Comment: in mysql_connect, username is name OR root ?

Comment: I'm actually just using my name which I've replaced with the word name here, like I said its updating only the quantity field now, connection to the db doesn't seem to be the issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
?>
<form action="updateinfo.php" method="post"
<tr>
  <td align="right">Partnumber:</td>
  <td align="left"><input type="text" name="partnumber" value="<?php echo $row['partnumber'];?>"/></td>
</tr>
```

If this loop runs 5 times:

1. You are creating 5 different forms without a `</form>`
2. You are only posting one field `partnumber`
3. In your UPDATE query that partnumber gets updated with same partnumber and hence no change is visible since no other field is being posted

Comment: After doing some testing, I see that I am able to update the quantity column, however the rest of the columns are not updating appropriately, I'm not sure where I'm going wrong, but I'm getting closer.